# Is it possible to run php exec through cygwin?

Tags: php, linux, cygwin, wamp

Hey guys I have one php exec command that works on my remote linux server but not my windows (WAMP package) local server. I really want to create an identical workstation so I can test locally and then update my remote server. If anyone has any suggestions or solutions other than converting to linux, I would really appreciate it.

```
<?php

$safe_path = escapeshellarg('fake-virus.txt');

$command = '/usr/bin/clamscan --stdout ' . $safe_path;

$out = '';

$int = -1;

exec($command, $out, $int);



echo $int;



if ($int == 0) {

    // all good;

} else {

    echo 'o no';// VIRUS!;

}





?>
```

Comment: Have you tried just running php.exe from the php dir in C:\wamp?

Comment: I don't quite understand, what I am trying to do though is keep the same command so I do not have to change code to test locally vs remote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I really want to create an identical workstation so I can test locally and then update my remote server

Installing `cygwin` is the wrong way to go about this. Just use `virtualbox`, which you can get from **[here](http://www.virtualbox.org/)**, and run an Ubuntu VM. Much easier (and nicer).

Comment: sounds like a good idea, will I have to use xampp server lol? It has been giving my trouble with PDO.

Comment: Use whatever server you want. Apache is typically the most common choice, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'su' it works great for me when doing cool cross OS stuff

```
shell_exec('su Administrator -c "cmd/script"');
```

Its not that difficult to run cygwin with Apache PHP and more. Here is a pretty simple tutorial [cygwin-apache-php](http://victormiti.umusebo.com/blog/installing-and-configuring-apache-php-mysql-on-cygwin) Have fun!

Answer (score -1):

At least in one instance I was able to use  shell_exec() of php of wamp (on windows:-)) via cygwin. I had to install procps or something in the cygwin installer to have a top command of sorts in cygwin. Then I was able to use wamps php shell_exec to perform that cygwin top command using Kishans suggestion in http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php:

```
<?php
echo $result = shell_exec("C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login  -c '/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/top.exe --b -n 1'");

?>
```

/////////////////
Kisha's remarks cited:

If you are on windows and has Cygwin, You can execute all your Cygwin binaries using shell_exec() as follows:

```
<?
$result = shell_exec("C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login  -c '/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/convert.exe --version'");
print($result);
?>
```

The key is the "--login"  option which appends all the required common cygwin binary and library paths to $PATH. Without this option some of the cygwin binaries that links to other libraries ( Like ImageMagick binaries which links to X11 ) will not work and you may see errors like "cygX11-6.dll not found, Could not start convert.exe"